# Making An Array of Selected Values That Only Displays Specific Values

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to print out a second array that is based off my first one but only displays values that are greater than the value to its left and less than the value to it's right and displaying these values by row in the row that they are in the original array. Here's my code so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
       int row, col, i, j;
       int arr[][] = new int[10][10];
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


       row = 3;
       col = 6;

       // enter array elements.
       for(i=0; i<row; i++)
       {
           for(j=0; j<col; j++)
           {
               System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
               arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
           }
       }

       // the 2D array is here.
       System.out.print("Matrix Display :\n");
       for(i=0; i<row; i++)
       {
           for(j=0; j<col; j++)
           {
               System.out.print(arr[i][j]+ "  ");
           }
           System.out.println();


       }

       System.out.println(arr[0]);
       System.out.println(arr[1]);
       System.out.println(arr[2]);
       System.out.println(arr[3]);

   }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't know how many of the elements fit your criteria, so you need to use a mutable object. Since each row might have a different number of matching numbers, you won't be able to make a normal array without null values in it most of the time.

Use a 2D `ArrayList`, scan through your original 2D array, and add the value that match your criteria to the corresponding row of your `ArrayList`.

You could do something like this:

```
int width = arr[0].length-1;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listoflists= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();


// Scan array for matching values
for(i=0; i<row; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
        listoflists.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        if(j==0 && arr[i][0]<arr[i][1])
            listoflist.get(i).add(arr[i][0]);
        else if(j==width && arr[i][width]>arr[i][width-1]
            listoflist.get(i).add(arr[i][width]);
        else if( #this is the last condition to check from both sides)
            listoflist.get(i).add(arr[i][j]);

    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that, I'm not super proficient in java

Comment: You can try something like what I did in the edit. a 2D `ArrayList` is actually is list of lists, so each new row in the array you add a new list and then add the values you find to the list corresponding to the row in the array